# sharing screen by the teacher for the students in the classroom

Tags: windows, osx-lion, screen-sharing

I have a Macbook with OSX Lion installed and I'm teaching a class of 10 students.
All of them have windows laptops.

I want to share my screen with them in the class instead of using a projector.

What are the options available with and without internet.

Comment: You could use software called VNC. You install a VNC server (Mac may already have one built-in!) On the machine you want people to see. You then run VNC viewing software on the other machines. The VNC on the other computers (clients) then go to your Mac's IP on the network and can see your screen and all the mouse moves etc. BTW you can set the VNC server to not let people take control of your Mac (so they can't mess around)...

Comment: Try these instructions http://www.dssw.co.uk/blog/2007-05-14-a-vnc-server-is-included-in-mac-os-x-104/ bit don't do the option to set the ability for clients to control your machine.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is to use [screencast software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_screencasting_software). These all require a network connection.

Screencasting is actually a small part of a larger industry which includes all video conferencing software\hardware. You will find that most of [these products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_video_telecommunication_services_and_product_brands) will also do what you need.

Another possibility is to use [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software) software for this (this link mixes them in with RDP software so be careful to choose the correct items). These programs aren't specifically meant for this purpose though and may waste a lot of resources. These will also require a network connection.

Without using the network you have a few options which I can think of:

- Use the projector which you've already said that you don't want.
- You could use a large TV instead of a projector (which may be cheating a little since this is basically the same thing; the main difference is that this won't wash out in high light conditions).
- This concept could be extended even further by using a [specialty device](http://www.provideoinstruments.com/pro-video-instruments-vecoax-tx-dual-channel-hdmi-hd-rf-modulator-solution.pdf) (read this as meaning VERY expensive) which converts your digital output to RF (meaning that you could tune into a channel on your TV and pick up the output as a standard TV station).
- My last option is to use a video camera to record your screen which will then be able to use one of the other methods to transmit back to individual computers. This is really not much different than the other options after that point but if you cannot add software to your computer (and do not have a large display) then this may be the only option for you.